# In Rails, use nested_form for adding items to table rows do not work in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using simple_nested_form to add items to table rows, directed by this https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/wiki/How-To:-Render-nested-fields-inside-a-table.

It works very well in development environments. However, after I deployed this project to my server, there is no response when clicking the add button.

Here is my code:

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @rule, :wrapper => false do |f| %>
  <%#= f.error_notification %>
  <%= render 'shared/the_error_messages' %>

  <%= render 'basic_info', f: f %>

  <div>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_basic_info.html.erb

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>age>=</th>
    <th>age<=</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='fields'>
  <%= f.fields_for :basic_infos, :wrapper => false do |f| %>
    <tr class='fields'>
      <td>
        <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
        <%= f.input :age_lower_bound, label: false, as: :integer%>
      </td>
      <td><%= f.input :age_upper_bound, label: false, as: :integer%></td>
      <td><%= f.link_to_remove 'Remove' %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.link_to_add 'Add basic info', :basic_infos, :container =>'tbody', :fields_element=>'tr'%></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require_tree .

window.NestedFormEvents.prototype.insertFields = function(content, assoc, link) {
    var $tr = $(link).closest('tr');
    return $(content).insertBefore($tr);
}
```

I have spent many days to try different ways to deploy and checked the installation of nodejs.
Can anyone help me? Thx

Comment: what happens when you try to run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` ?  Also are you using `simple_form` ?

Comment: I got this `yarn install v1.15.2 [1/4] Resolving packages...success Already up-to-date.Done in 0.08s.` when I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: are you using simple_form ?

Comment: I used `nested_form_for` before, and now I use `simple_nested_form_for` since it is more convenient.

Comment: do you see any error on the browser's console? you can also add a `debugger:` line inside that `insertFields` function to debug it the code is actually being called.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `rails-ujs` and `jquery-ui` in file `application.js`.
Now it looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require_tree .
```

Now it works well on my server.

However, I still don't know why it works. Can someone explain to me?